# Zeros and poles...of poles?

Tags: complex-analysis, control-theory

I'm new to poles and zeros, so I'm just looking for some clarity to help my research endeavor. If I'm given an integral of the form

$$\iint \frac{P(u,v)}{Q(u,v)}\,dudv$$

and I'm asked to identify the poles of the integrand on the $u$-plane, then I need to find the roots of

$$Q(u,v) = 0$$

My question is, what happens if the roots of $Q(u,v)$ are rational functions? For example, say

$$Q(u,v) = u(v-1)^2 - (av)^2$$

the poles on the $u$-plane are given by

$$u = \left(\frac{av}{v-1}\right)^2$$

which is a rational expression. Does this pole also have "zeros and poles" of its own? Is there something significant to be said when poles are rational?

Comment: In what context are you defining poles? I see you tagged complex analysis.... is this integral happening over $\mathbb C^2$? Is this integral merely over $\mathbb R^2$ and you have split the complex integral into two real integrals?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I've encountered poles and zeros while reading about complex analysis in which they usually use $z = x+iy$ (or $z = re^{i\theta}$) as the variable. Most examples I've encountered discuss complex integration and residues over a single $z$-plane. That being said, I tried to express my question as if I had 2 complex variables. Hope my that helps to bring some clarity (or least place my train of thought).

Comment: In general you will get algebraic curves as roots systems. The answers to your questions here seem to be that you should study the field of Several Complex Variables.

Comment: O boy...after a quick read (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Several_complex_variables), looks pretty complex